# Nav bar toggle javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make toggle nav but unfortunately not working

```
function navtoggle(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
        }
    </script>
```

```css
.sidebar.active {
    width:0px;
}
```

Comment: you are using document.getElementsByClassName.. and it returns a node list.. try document.querySelector('.sidebar')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar').classList  is a HTMLCollection, you must loop through it or pick a specific index

```js
function navtoggle(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0].classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">Hello</div>
<button onClick="navtoggle();">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` will return a HTMLCollection instead of the single sidebar element you're trying to target. Because `classList` isn't a property of HTMLCollection, you'll simply get a TypeError when trying to toggle a class on this collection.

If you are sure there is only one element with `.sidebar` on the page, or that the sidebar you're trying to target is the first in the DOM, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0]`. An alternative approach would be to use `document.querySelector('.sidebar')`, where you can also pass a more specific selector, such as `document.querySelector('aside.sidebar')`, to ensure you've selected the right element. For example:

```js
function navtoggle() {
  document.querySelector('aside.sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.active {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

button {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  This is the sidebar
</aside>

<main>
  This is not the sidebar <br>
  <button onclick="navtoggle()">Toggle the sidebar</button>
</main>
```